# Buffer multiple events with StreamTransformer?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using flutter_blue to get a stream of data (List) from a bluetooth low energy device. I then need to transform this into a different stream of a different data type (Essentially a stream of Map<String, dynamic> / JSON).

My problem arises as 1 JSON event may consist of multiple events from the initial stream. Is there a way using StreamTransformers to buffer in multiple events to output a single event. I know the converse is possible, StreamTransformers can output multiple events for one input event.

Thanks.

Comment: for example: `class Buffer extends StreamTransformerBase<int, List<int>> {
Stream<List<int>> bind(Stream<int> stream) {
final sc = StreamController<List<int>>();
var buffer = <int>[];
stream.listen((i) {
buffer.add(i);
if (buffer.length == 3) {
sc.sink.add(buffer);
buffer = [];
}
}).onDone(() {
if (buffer.isNotEmpty) {
sc.sink.add(buffer);
}
sc.sink.close();
});
return sc.stream;
}
}`

Comment: of course you can do the same thing using `StreamTransformer.fromHandlers` where you have `EventSink`s provided and you dont have to create `StreamController`